# Xrdp login failed

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, vnc, xrdp, tightvncserver

I Am trying to login to Ubuntu machine from windows using RDP. Installed `xrdp` and tight vnc but while connecting am getting following error

```
xrdp_mm_process_login_response:login failed
```

Steps followed to install XRDP:

```
sudo apt-get update .
sudo apt-get install tightvncserver
sudo    apt-get install xrdp
sudo restart
```

After this tried logging with RDP and getting the error. could you give a step by step guide or other alternative methods, please?

Comment: I think it may help you solver this problem. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/106974/windows-remote-desktop-login-failed-with-ubuntu-server-12-4

Answer (score 7):

I managed to fix this problem by editing the `/etc/xrdp/sesman.ini` file and commenting out the requirement to group membership.  Now you can access all accounts.

```
[Security]
AllowRootLogin=1
MaxLoginRetry=4
#TerminalServerUsers=tsusers
#TerminalServerAdmins=tsadmins
```

Evidently a user must be a member of tsusers which is supposed to be created by xrdp itself.  This group was not created at xrdp installation in my case.  I created the group and added users to the group.  But this did not help.   By commenting out the following lines, all users can rdp now.

Answer (score 3):

Your x11 sessions might be locked or orphaned.

[see this article](http://linuxtoolkit.blogspot.nl/2013/03/xrdpmmprocessloginresponse-login-failed.html)

> If you encountered this error `xrdp_mm_process_login_response: login failed` when you use the remote desktop connection to connection to a vnc session.
>
> Even if you restart `xrdp`, the error still remains, the issue could be due to locked X11 session that was created by `xrdp`.
>
> To solve the issue, go to `/tmp/.X11-unix/` and find your X session and delete the session.
>
> ```
> cd /tmp/.X11-unix
> ```
>
> Do a listing
>
> ```
> ls -l
> ```
>
> Look at the sessions owned by you which you wished to delete
>
> ```
> .....
> .....
> srwxrwxrwx 1 root      root  0 Jul  9  2012 X0
> srwxrwxrwx 1 user1  users 0 Jan 25 09:13 X1
> srwxrwxrwx 1 user2      users 0 Jul 10  2012 X10
> srwxrwxrwx 1 user3     users 0 Feb 19 13:31 X11
> srwxrwxrwx 1 user4  users 0 Nov 20 15:10 X12
> srwxrwxrwx 1 user5     users 0 Jul 10  2012 X13
> .....
> ```
>
> Delete the session...
>
> If `xrdp` still fails, it seems that it is due to orphaned X--. Once `xrdp` hits an orphaned X-- which may or may not be from other users, the error will still remain.
>
> To see the orphaned X11 session, you can run `vncserver`, which will return something like this
>
> ```
> $ vncserver
> Warning: Head-Node:1 is taken because of /tmp/.X11-unix/X1
> Remove this file if there is no X server Head-Node:1
> ```
>
> Delete all the orphaned X--
>
> Restart the `xrdp` service and try the remote connection.
>
> ```
> service xrdp restart
> ```

Answer (score 3):

Usually this error means that the password used is not the valid one (or credentials are not valid ones).

You should know that the XRDP login screen will use by default the English US keyboard layout.  So, if you are using a different keyboard layout, you might be typing the wrong password in the xrdp login.  Check that keyboard layout is correct... Just a guess :-)

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem as well. All I had to do was to use lower case for my user name at the RDP login prompt. I have a user name which includes an upper case character.

Answer (score 1):

A less common, but hopefully useful solution to anyone else having this problem in a tunnel server setup similar to mine:

```
+--------------------------+            +-------------------+            +----------------+
| Mac OS X + MS RDP client | ==[ssh]==> | Ubuntu SSH server | ==[rdp]==> | Ubuntu Desktop |
+--------------------------+            +-------------------+            +----------------+
```

You must put the username and password **into your MS RDP client**. If you try and add it later at the remote login screen, you will first get the error. And when you try to log in using the remote login screen, you get `password failed`, `error - problem connecting`

#### Other info

In case you want to do RDP tunneling over an SSH like me, here is what I did:

```
ssh -v -N -L 3389:192.168.1.3:3389  me@mypublicsshserver.mydomain.com
```

Answer (score 0):

That might be because xrdp *latest version has a bug.* Check the log, to find if it's latest:

```
# sudo cat /var/log/apt/history.log
```

Install xrdp with this version:

```
# sudo apt-get install xrdp=0.6.1-2
```

Re-start xrdp:

```
# sudo service xrdp restart
```

It should work!

Until this is fix, to prevent future updates in the meantime:

```
# sudo apt-mark hold xrdp
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find your hostname by using `ifconfig`

To locate your ipaddress (the number beside "inet addr:")

Enter:

```
nslookup "your ip address"
```

Use the name that is returned in the Windows RDP client