# Ubuntu Remote Desktop Failed: Login Failed for Display 0

Tags: remote-desktop, xrdp, remote-login

Relatively new Ubuntu user here who's trying to learn how to setup a remote desktop. I've tried to do so on Ubuntu 18.04.4 to connect from a Windows 10 PC but I keep getting the same error "Login Failed for Display 0". The Remote Desktop Connection recognizes the computer since it displays the proper computer name during login. It's exactly the same issue mentioned [here](http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=13390) but none of the solutions worked. I've already spent several days going through various forums trying out all solutions but none of them have worked. Some of the ones I've tried are:

[18.04.3 Ubuntu LTS XRDP login failed for display 0](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1164456/18-04-3-lts-xrdp-login-failed-for-display-0)

[XRDP Login Failed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/773626/xrdp-login-failed)

[XRDP on Ubuntu 18.04LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1031519/xrdp-on-ubuntu-18-04lts)

The username/password are correct, checked multiple times already so it is not that or the keyboard. Whenever I attempt to connect I always make sure to be logged out of the Ubuntu computer but still have it on. What could the problem be? Quite confused as to what it could be.